# TextView capitalizes first two characters instead of one

Tags: swift, text, uitextview

So I've added placeholder functionality to UITextView, and now it capitalizes the first two characters of input text instead of one as it's supposed to.

I would appreciate you guys' help in solving this problem if you can help in any way. I've been trying, but I seem to be getting nowhere.

Here's the code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        textView.delegate = self
        textView.text = "Type something"
        textView.textColor = UIColor.rgb(197, 197, 199)
    }

}

extension ViewController: UITextViewDelegate {

    // Put cursor at the beginning of TextView when editing begins
    func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        textView.selectedTextRange = textView.textRange(from: textView.beginningOfDocument, to: textView.beginningOfDocument)
    }

    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        // Sets placeholder for UITextView
        let updatedText = (textView.text as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: text)
        if updatedText.isEmpty {
            textView.text = "Type something"
            textView.textColor = UIColor.rgb(197, 197, 199)
            textView.selectedTextRange = textView.textRange(from: textView.beginningOfDocument, to: textView.beginningOfDocument)
        } else if textView.textColor == UIColor.rgb(197, 197, 199) && !text.isEmpty {
            textView.textColor = UIColor.black
            textView.text = text
        } else {
            return true
        }
    
        return false
    }

    // Prevents selecting the placeholder
    func textViewDidChangeSelection(_ textView: UITextView) {
        if self.view.window != nil {
            if textView.textColor == UIColor.rgb(197, 197, 199) {
                textView.selectedTextRange = textView.textRange(from: textView.beginningOfDocument, to: textView.beginningOfDocument)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Typo - `textView.text = text` should be `textView.text = updatedText`

Comment: @rmaddy Tried that, with this change if I type "N" the result will be "NType something"

Comment: Ah right, due to your fake placeholder. It might be a lot simpler to use an extra label over your text view as a placeholder. Show and hide it as needed. Then you can have more normal logic in your text view.

Comment: @maddy, thanks, I didn't think about that, the label version does seem simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code below solves capitalization of the first 2 letters in text view.

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    if textView.text.isEmpty {
        textView.text = "Type something"
        textView.textColor = self.placeholderTextColor
    } else {
        textView.textColor = .black
    }
}

func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    if text.isEmpty {
        let updatedText = (textView.text as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: text)
        if updatedText.isEmpty {
            textView.text = "Type something"
            textView.textColor = self.placeholderTextColor
            textView.selectedRange = NSRange(location: 0, length: 0)
        }
    } else {
        if textView.text == "Type something" {
            textView.text = ""
        }
        textView.textColor = .black
    }
    return true
}
```

The reason why the text view capitalized first 2 characters in text view is that you've returned **false** in below delegate method

> func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool